# Run Two Loops Parallely in iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift

Is it possible to run two While loops parallely in Swift Programming Languages. Both of the loops are independent but both are heavy process going.

Is it possible to run two loops at a time

Comment: What kind of heavy processing your loops doing anyway?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it's possible. You just have to run both loops on **separate threads.**

It's general rule: If you want to run two processes in the same time, you have to run them separately.

---

Example code which you can just copy and paste to playground to see how it works:

```
//DispatchQueue(label: "com.app.queue1", qos: .background).async {
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
    while true {
        print(1)
        sleep(1)
    }
}
//DispatchQueue(label: "com.app.queue2", qos: .background).async {
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
    while true {
        print(2)
        sleep(1)
    }
}
```

... you can also use just main thread and one background. It depends on what you need. But the main idea is the same, you have to have separate threads.

Comment: Can you please give in Small Code wise explanation

Comment: By the way, you are not really making sure that they are run on different threads. They will probably run on the same queue and thread.

Answer (score 1):

You can call it in 2 separate background threads.

```
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
   // function 1
}

DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
   // function 2
}
```

Since these are background threads, if you want to do, then do something in the main thread, you'll have to switch to the `DispatchQueue.main.`

If you want to run them on 2 separate queues, you can make them something like

```
let backgroundQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "loadQueueOne", qos: .background)
backgroundQueue.async {
    // function 1
}
```

You can similarly create another one, separate, for the second queue.

Comment: @Sulthan I figured that op just wanted to run 2 things in background, but I've updated the answer. Thanks for pointing it out. :)

Comment: That solution is the correct, I was just commenting the explanation :) That background queue is parallel therefore the chances are it will be executed on two threads but you cannot really be sure of that.

Comment: Yup. And I do appreciate your feedback. Cheers. :)